# How to Import NetworManangementClient in Azure using Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli

I want to obtain the public IP of a NIC interface in Azure using Python SDK. So, I need to import NetworkManagemenClient.

But when I do the following:

"from azure.mgmt.compute import NetworkManagementClient" or "from azure.mgmt.resource import NetworkManagementClient"

I am not able to import.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, you can't import the NetworkManagementClient from the compute or the resource namespace.
I'm surprised you thought this could work actually?

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/network

Comment: So, I used # network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id), followed by                                                                                                                                           #net_interface = network_client.network_interfaces.get(nic_group, nic_name).                But network_interfaces is not an attribute for network client. Where can I get the attributes for the object network_client? PS: nic_group and nic_name has been obtained.

Comment: `network_interfaces` is definitely an attribute of any network client. Be sure to have at least package version 1.0, and ideally even 2.0.